# Exporting props from SvelteKit load() function

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component, sveltekit

I am trying to create a dynamically updating navbar in SvelteKit, with the currently open section formatted accordingly. I am attempting to identify the page based on the first part of the path, as below:

`__layout.svelte`:

```
<script context="module">
    export const load = ({ page }) => {
        return {
            props: {
                currentSection: `${page.path}`.split('/')[0],
                sections: ['home', 'dashboard', 'settings']
            }
        };
    }
</script>

<div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
    <Header {...props} />
    <slot />
</div>
```

`Header.svelte`

```
<script>
    import Menu from "$lib/nav/menu.svelte"
</script>

<Menu {...props}></Menu>
```

`Menu.svelte`

```
<script>
    export let sections;
    export let currentSection;
</script>

{#each sections as { section }}
    <a
        href="/{section}"
        class="{section == currentSection
            ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white'
            : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700'} other-classes"
        >{section}</a
    >
{/each}
```

This is resulting in a `props is not defined` error, but I would have expected props to be defined since I've defined it in the return from the `load()` fundtion on the primary layout (based on the [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#loading-output-props)).

Do I somehow need to explicitly declare the props rather than expecting them to be available from the return of the `load()` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `props` are passed from the *module* script to the regular component *script*, this means you still need to add `export let props` in your layout as well.

```html
<script context="module">
  export const load = () => {
    return {
      props: {
        test: 123
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<script>
  export let test; //
</script>
```

Note that this will always spread out the props, you cannot do `export let props` and retrieve *all the props*, you can however get all the props passed to a component using `$$props`

Also, the load function is only available for pages and layouts, so you will for sure have to export props in both Header and Menu as those are just regular svelte components.

Comment: The `props is not defined` error is in `__layout.svelte` so the props never get to the component - do the props need to be explicitly declared in the layout too, even though they are being returned by the load function? That's the basis of the question.

Comment: Yes, it still has to do so, `__layout` is a component (almost) like any other

Comment: Perhaps you could update your answer to show how that is done?